# MENDELEY - error foreign key constraint failed

Tags: database, mendeley

i am using ubuntu 16-x and Mendeley desktop as a reference manager. all of a sudden i got the error 'foreign key constraint failed'. i re-installed mendeley but the problem persists? how can i solve it? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the Mendeley team, so I am posting it for completeness.

>

Follow this path: ~/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/

Look for your SQL file and delete it. It should look like this: youremailaddress@www.mendeley.com.sqlite or delete the entire Mendeley Desktop folder.

Uninstall and reinstall Mendeley Desktop.
Log back in to Mendeley Desktop. Sync your library to re-download your database from the Web.

If this does not help, delete the entire desktop folder.  Please be sure to delete the Mendeley desktop folder and not the Mendeley Ltd folder, since this will just delete the application. Don't worry about deleting the folder as you will regain all your data upon syncing when the application opens.